# my if else statements don't work and command everything

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ans = input("Enter yes or no: ") 


if ans != "Yes" or "yes" or "no" or "No":
    print("Can't do that") 

if ans == "yes" or "Yes": 
    print("Great!")

if ans == "no" or "No": 
    print("Okay, then")
```

> If I type let's say "Okay" it outputs this:

Can't do that!
Great!
Okay, then

instead of "Can't do that". I don't know what's wrong, and I couldn't find questions like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

do instead something more pythonic:

```
if ans.lower() in ['no', 'yes']:
```

and use `elif` instead of doing another if verification.

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
ans = input("Enter yes or no: ") 

if ans in ["Yes", "yes"]:
    print("Great!")
elif ans in ["No", "no"]: 
    print("Okay, then") 
else:
  print("Can't do that")
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to ask for upvotes to all your answers?

Comment: Certainly it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Test whether the answer is in a list or a set (using sets in the example below). Otherwise, your first condition evaluates to `True`. This is because of the operator precedence, Python considers it equivalent to `(ans != "Yes") or ("yes") or ("no") or ("No")`. And `"yes"` is `True` because it is not an empty string ([docs](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), which makes the whole expression evaluate to `True` as well.

```
ans = input("Enter yes or no: ") 


if ans not in {"Yes", "yes", "no", "No"}:
    print("Can't do that") 

if ans in {"yes", "Yes"}: 
    print("Great!")

if ans in {"no" or "No"}: 
    print("Okay, then")
```

Better still, make it shorter like so:

```
ans = input('Enter yes or no: ').lower() 

if ans == 'yes': 
    print('Great!')
elif ans == 'no': 
    print('Okay, then')
else:
    print("Can't do that")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to use logical operators in a programming language, it should be:

```
if (ans != "Yes") or (ans != "yes") or (ans != "no") or (ans != "No")
```

As you see, you should always repeat your variable.

Answer (score -1):

the or operator assignment is not right please try this

ans = input("Enter yes or no: ")

if ans != "Yes" or "yes" or "no" or "No":
print("Can't do that")

if ans == "yes" or "Yes":
print("Great!")

if ans == "no" or "No":
print("Okay, then")

you can either write
if ans in ('stringone', 'stringtwo'):
dosomething()

Or you can write separate equality tests,

```
if var == 'stringone' or var == 'stringtwo':
    dosomething()
```